# retroceder o contador de clique sinalizando onde parou

Tags: javascript, html, css

Procurei criar um **contador progresssivo e regressivo** para marcar em que `tag` esta parado.

## Código

```js
el = document.getElementsByTagName('a')

var x = 0,
    y = 0;

document.getElementById('menos').onclick = function() {

    x--;

    if (y == 3 || x == 0)
        alert("Limite!");
    else {
        el[x].className = 'ativo';
        el[y].className = '';
    }
    y++;
}


document.getElementById('mais').onclick = function() {

    x++;

    if (y == 3 || x == 4)
        alert("Limite!");
    else {
        el[y].className = '';
        el[x].className = 'ativo';
    }
    y++;
}
```

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer; padding: 3px; text-decoration: none; color: #111;
}
a.ativo {
  font-weight: bolder;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button id="menos">&#171 Anterior</button>

<a href="#A" class="ativo" >1</a>
<a href="#B">2</a>
<a href="#C">3</a>
<a href="#D">4</a>

<button id="mais">Próximo &#187</button>
```

> Veja que retroceder o contador, não funciona de maneira esperada, que seria igual ao avançar, pulando de uma-em-uma casa. Fiz diversas modificações e não resultou em nada.

Preciso que me ajudem a solucionar este pequeno equívoco. Voltar para traz do mesmo modo jeito que foi pra frente **sinalizando de uma em uma**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que podes simplificar o teu código para isto:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('a')
var btns = document.getElementsByTagName('button')
var x = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener('click', mudarPágina);
}

function mudarPágina() {
    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) { // fazer reset
        els[i].classList.remove('ativo');
    }
    var incr = this.id == 'mais' ? 1 : -1;
    x = x + incr;
    if (x < 0) x = 0;
    else if (x > els.length - 1) x = els.length - 1;
    els[x].classList.add('ativo');
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pye0p7fz/1/

Assim fica menos repetido, tens a lógica toda numa só função e só precisas de ler o id `mais` `menos` para saber que direção tomar.

Answer (score 0):

Além da reposta de **@Sergio** deixo mais uma alternativa, com uma breve **modificação** no meu **Código Fonte** incluso na **Pergunta**.

Este `script` por sua vez, trabalha em qualquer versão de navegadores desde, antigos ao atuais. Confira:

## Código

```js
el = document.getElementsByTagName('a')

var x = 0, y = 0;

function voltar()
{
  
  if(x == 0) x = alert("Limite!");

for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++){
  el[i].className = "";
}
  el[x].className = "color";
  
  x--;

}
function avancar()
{
if(y == 5 || x == 6) y = alert("Limite!");
else {
el[y].className = "";
el[x].className = "color";
}
y++;
}
```

```css
a
{ 
text-decoration: none;

cursor: pointer;

padding: 3px; 

color: black; 
}

a.color {
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<a onclick="voltar(5)" id="menos">&#171 Anterior</a>

<a>1</a>
<a>2</a>
<a>3</a>
<a>4</a>
<a>5</a>

<a onclick="avancar(x++)" id="mais">Próximo &#187</a>
```